# ¿Cómo dar animaciones al aparecer un elemento cuando se hace click en un boton?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transform, transition

¿Me podrían ayudar? Tengo el siguiente código

```
.login__part-one {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.login__part-two {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}
```

Pero la transición no funciona, en este caso es cuando se presiona siguiente y se muestra esta sección. Por ende no puedo usar pseoudo-clases en este elemento ¿hay forma de crear darle transiciones únicamente cuando presione el botón "Siguiente" y aparezca de manera suave.

```
const btnNextLogin = document.querySelector('.login__part-one > .btn-n-primary');
const btnBackLogin = document.querySelector('.login__part-two > .btn-n-secondary');
const partOneLogin = document.querySelector('.login__part-one');
const partTwoLogin = document.querySelector('.login__part-two');

if (partOneLogin && partTwoLogin) {
    btnNextLogin.addEventListener('click' , () => {
        partOneLogin.style.display = "none";
        partTwoLogin.style.display = "initial";
    });
    
    btnBackLogin.addEventListener('click' , () => {
        partOneLogin.style.display = "initial";
        partTwoLogin.style.display = "none";
    });    
}
```

Estos son los elementos que deben aparecer con la transición cuando se presione el boton:

```
<form class="form__login" action="/routers/home.html">
            <img class="login__img" src="/assets/imgs/logo-taxis-libres.png" alt="Logo Taxis Libres">
            <h1 class="login__title">Pide un taxi</h1>
            <p class="login__text">desde el computador</p>
            <h2 class="login__subtitle">Crear cuenta</h2>
            <fieldset class="login__part-one">
                <label class="login__label" for="">
                    <input class="login__input" type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" placeholder="Nombre completo" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]*$" required>
                </label>
                <label class="login__label" for="">
                    <input class="login__input" type="number" name="celular" id="celular" placeholder="Celular" required>
                </label>
                <button class="btn-n btn-n-primary">Siguiente</button>
                <a class="btn-n btn-n-secondary" href="/index.html">Volver</a>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="login__part-two">
                <label class="login__label" for="">
                    <input class="login__input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Correo" required>
                </label>
                <label class="login__label" for="">
                    <span class="icon icon-eye-block"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-eye"></span>
                    <input class="login__input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                </label>
                <span class="login__text__small">Al crear cuenta acepto <a class="login__link__small btn-n" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">politica de tratamiento de datos</a></span>
                <input class="btn-n btn-n-primary" type="submit" value="Crear cuenta">
                <button class="btn-n btn-n-secondary">Volver</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Muchas gracias por su atención

Comment: Hace falta más información. Por favor, edita tu pregunta tratando de crear [un ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo con **clases**, en donde agregas o quitas la clase dependiendo el botón *clickeado*, la clase la defines en el **CSS** con los estilos y transición definidos, al asignar la clase es cuando puedes observar la animación, ejemplo:

```js
const btnNextLogin = document.querySelector('.login__part-one > .btn-n-primary');
const btnBackLogin = document.querySelector('.login__part-two > .btn-n-secondary');
const partOneLogin = document.querySelector('.login__part-one');
const partTwoLogin = document.querySelector('.login__part-two');

if (partOneLogin && partTwoLogin) {
  btnNextLogin.addEventListener('click', () => {
    partOneLogin.classList.add("ocultar");
    partTwoLogin.classList.remove("ocultar");
  });

  btnBackLogin.addEventListener('click', () => {
    partOneLogin.classList.remove("ocultar");
    partTwoLogin.classList.add("ocultar");
  });
}
```

```css
.login__part-one {
  height: 30px;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  width: 90%;
}

.login__part-two {
  height: 30px;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  width: 90%;
}

/*En ocultar agrego el visibility hidden para que el elemento se oculte definitivamente*/
.ocultar {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form class="form__login" action="/routers/home.html">
  <img class="login__img" src="/assets/imgs/logo-taxis-libres.png" alt="Logo Taxis Libres">
  <h1 class="login__title">Pide un taxi</h1>
  <p class="login__text">desde el computador</p>
  <h2 class="login__subtitle">Crear cuenta</h2>
  <fieldset class="login__part-one">
    <label class="login__label" for="">
      <input class="login__input" type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" placeholder="Nombre completo" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]*$" required>
    </label>
    <label class="login__label" for="">
      <input class="login__input" type="number" name="celular" id="celular" placeholder="Celular" required>
    </label>
    <button class="btn-n btn-n-primary">Siguiente</button>
    <a class="btn-n btn-n-secondary" href="/index.html">Volver</a>
  </fieldset>

  <!--Aqui desde un principio le asignamos la clase para que permanezca oculta hasta el click del boton siguiente-->
  <fieldset class="login__part-two ocultar">
    <label class="login__label" for="">
      <input class="login__input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Correo" required>
    </label>
    <label class="login__label" for="">
      <span class="icon icon-eye-block"></span>
      <span class="icon icon-eye"></span>
      <input class="login__input" type="password" name="password"   id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
    </label>
    <span class="login__text__small">Al crear cuenta acepto <a class="login__link__small btn-n" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">politica de tratamiento de datos</a></span>
    <input class="btn-n btn-n-primary" type="submit" value="Crear cuenta">
    <button class="btn-n btn-n-secondary">Volver</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hay mejores formas de realizarlo, pero tome en cuenta el código que ya tenias y te doy una solución sencilla, dime si te sirvió.

Comment: La verdad no funciono. Se no realiza la transición y la segunda pantalla no se muestra nunca

Comment: El problema es que el visibility=hidden oculta el elemento, pero reserva el espacio a diferencia del display=none